# Polymer - How do I attach an observer to an array?

Tags: javascript, polymer

How do I attach an observer to a polymer attribute that is an array?  To be clear, I want callbacks when items in the array change.  For simplicity, let's say my array is:

```
[
    { text: 'foo' },
    { text: 'bar' }
]
```

I want something like:

```
observe : {
    'items.text' : 'itemsChanged'
}
```

The following works, but is obviously un-sustainable:

```
observe : {
    'items[0].text' : 'itemsChanged',
    'items[1].text' : 'itemsChanged'
}
```

Note that in my case, the changes are coming from another polymer element that I have control over.  So if I could somehow trigger a change from the element that has control over `{ text: 'foo' }`, that would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

To be clear, Polymer will automatically observe Arrays, but an 'ArrayObserver' will only tell you if (a) the Array itself is replaced or (b) items are added, removed, or rearranged. Just like observed objects, Polymer does not automatically observe properties of sub-objects.

> > the changes are coming from another polymer element that I have control over

This is usually the case and we typically have the element doing the changing fire an event for communication.

Comment: I know this, but it doesn't answer my question of how to observe elements in an array.  I don't want to do it through events because I'm having a different issue trying to figure out how to get the target dom node through `::shadow`

Comment: There is no way to observe all the objects in an array without setting up observers for them individually, which is a bad idea ("unsustainable", in your words). Using events is the better avenue, perhaps you can explain your problem better? Suggest avoid trying to get the target dom node, and instead send useful information in `event.detail`.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late, but because the question ranks quite high on google and none of the above is really helping, here is my solution:

Polymer ships with [observe.js](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js) and this helps solving your problem.

The basic version would be to use the `ArrayObserver` but this only fires when the array gets altered, meaning when elements are added, removed and i guess also when you replace an entry. But this won't help if you wanna observe changes to object properties in an array - such as in your case.

Here it's better to use the `CompoundObserver` and add all paths via `addPath` or `addObserver(new PathObserver(obj, '...'))`. But you have to iterate over the whole array and add all observed properties in a loop for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.observe() to accomplish this. e.g.:

```
ready: function() {
    Object.observe(this.items, this.myObserver);
}
myObserver: function (changes){
    changes.forEach(function(change, i){
        console.log('what property changed? ' + change.name);
        console.log('how did it change? ' + change.type);
        console.log('whats the current value? ' + change.object[change.name]);
        console.log(change); // all changes
    });
},
```

More [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/).

Comment: `Object.observe` isn't supported by anything other than Chrome

Comment: No, it's not.  Useful solutions are usable.

Comment: Someone has written a polyfill for this: https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe

Comment: TypeError: Object.observe is not a function

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation for this

[Observe array mutations](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#array-observation)