# How to have reactive global variables in polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, reactive-programming, polymer-1.0

I followed the documentation at https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#global and learnt about the global variables that can be shared across all the instances of a given component. I would like to go a step further. Would like to have the global variable to be reactive. Meaning if its value is changed by one of the instances, it should propagate through all other instances.

```html
<dom-module is="my-writer">
  <template>
    <my-global user="{{username}}"></my-global>
    <button on-click="changeName">Change</button>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-writer', 
    changeName: function() { this.username = 'abhilash'; }
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>


<dom-module is="my-reader">
  <template>
    <my-global user="{{username}}"></my-global>
    <span>{{username}}</span>
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-reader',
    properties: {
      username: { type: String, notify: true, value: 'goje' }
    }
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<my-writer></my-writer>
<my-reader></my-reader>
```

This code would show a `button` and a `span` with value as 'goje'. And when I click button, I would want the `span` to change to show 'abhilash'.

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer 1.0 you may achieve something similar with `iron-meta` elements. These share the information stored throughout the whole webpage.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta

This is half way, the missing part is actually the notification/updating. This actually depends on your implementation i reckon.

Further hints and various implementations can be found here:
[Polymer 1.0 Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849816/polymer-1-0-global-variables?rq=1)