# data persistence across elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

suppose I want to have a data provider element for my user, like

```
<user-data-provider user-data="{{data}}"></user-data-provider>
```

which sends an ajax request and gets the logged in user.

Suppose I want to access my user data in different pages, and I add this tag to wherever I need, but the problem is, every time the browser sees this tag, makes an ajax again and I have to wait until data is fetched!

I know I can make a variable in my main page and pass it along child pages, but that seems like overkill to me !

how can I persist user data across different pages and part of my app?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

There are different ways to do this.

1. You can use use a [monostate pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MonostatePattern)
2. You can have one instance of your `user-data-provider` element in your root element or index.html and use [iron-signals](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) to transmit the data to all other elements that want to consume it
3. You can use [iron-meta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta) to have global state
4. Use an external state management framework (i.e. redux). There is a polymer wrapper for it: [polymer-redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux)

I would recommend using an external state mangement framework such as redux.

Some of the solutions are shown here:

[Polymer 1.0 Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849816/polymer-1-0-global-variables)

Comment: Using redux for this little problem ?! it's like to call the genie for a couple of tea!

Comment: I think its better to use iron-meta for user detail and iron-signal for user state change event

Comment: the bigger the application gets, the more useful an external state management tool such as redux becomes. This way you keep your elements as simple and thus testable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I used [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) for my data store, and used polymer's [predefined elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/app-pouchdb) to work with it

now every time that I need data, I just use that component